# What do developers do during testing phase of a waterfall life cycle?

Tags: testing, waterfall

If the testing phase is over 5 months long do the developers help the testers execute scripts? I don't know how it's done in a waterfall lifecycle where the phases are usually quite long.

Comment: Fixing bugs generally.  Including, realistically, all the "feature not implemented yet" bugs that were frantically stubbed out before handing things over to QA.

Comment: They work on a new project. And any bugs found will be reported to a smaller team of developers that specialize in only fixing bugs in other people's code. That allows to streamline production, specialize people and process, and have a clear task for everyone at any point. *All hail the great pipeline!*

Comment: Something similar to this: https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: So you are working on a project with a dedicated period of 5 months with just tests & bugfixing, but no new features to be added or implemented? Just curious, but what kind of software product is this? Controller software for a nuclear power plant, or something similar?

Comment: ... or did the team 5 months of development without any tests, and now they are learning the hard way that this is not very efficient?

Comment: upgrading a timesheet application

Comment: @Snowman Challenge me if you dare!!! <======][==

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about other organizations, but in mine they love waterfall development.  The testers make the test scripts during the development.  And then during the test phase the developers spend almost all their time helping the testers figure out whether a test worked and if not why it failed.  If a test fails there is no way the testers can figure out:

- which of the dozen or so back end systems the request went to and whether it was supposed to go there
- which of the dozen or so middleware platforms the request went through and whether it was supposed to
- whether the correct response was sent from the back end to the middleware
- whether the correct response was sent from the middleware to the channel
- whether the different channels are meant to display the same thing when given the same data
- why their test data is wrong (it is almost always wrong)

The first two determine which log file the data is in - you can't figure out anything until you know where to look.  Since a simple yes or no answer to the customer might involve five or ten queries to multiple back end systems through multiple middleware platforms, it is really difficult to sort out which log files might contain your requests and responses.

The next two require reading very technical log files that are very verbose.  That means that they are effectively obfuscated.  (I think third parties make their log files hard to read so you have to engage their services when you have a high severity production fault.)  Since not all of the logs contain timestamps and all of them contain dozens of tester's simultaneous tests, it is really difficult to sort out which requests and responses are for your test.

The last one isn't really their fault - the test data needs to be integrated across all the back end systems but no single person knows how to create the test data in more than one system so it is infrequent to find a piece of test data that has been created with all the correct attributes in every back end system.

Because there are many many more testers than developers I spend nearly 6 hours a day doing "test support" during the test phase.

Comment: yes, this is also my experience